# In SQL, how to you join multiple aggregate queries (count or sum specifically)?

Tags: sql, join

I have a table that has the total number of different items per person. I am trying to create a new table that counts the number of people with a total of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, and 7+ items grouped by company and year. I think I have individual queries that accomplish this task, but I can't get a join to work in order to fill the new table. The individual queries that seem to accomplish what I am trying to do are:

```
SELECT 
    Company,
    YEAR(Date) as Year,
    COUNT(*) as items0_Count
FROM table
WHERE   items_total = 0
GROUP BY Company, YEAR(Date)
ORDER BY Company, YEAR(Date)

SELECT 
    Company,
    YEAR(Date) as Year,
    COUNT(*) as items1_Count
FROM table
WHERE   items_total = 1
GROUP BY Company, YEAR(Date)
ORDER BY Company, YEAR(Date)
```

I would obviously have that same query 8 times with only the where statement changing in order to generate the counts for each case, but only included two here to keep the question short. Hope this makes sense, and thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Company, YEAR(Date) as Year,
       SUM(CASE WHEN items_total = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as items0_Count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN items_total = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as items2_Count
FROM table
GROUP BY Company, YEAR(Date)
ORDER BY Company, YEAR(Date);
```

You can add additional columns for whatever item counts you want.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I tried something like that, but must have had something wrong in there.

Answer (score 0):

`Union all/ union` the two queries you have. You'll get the desired else follow @GordonLinoff's answer.

Also as an easy way try this below

```
  SELECT 
 Company,
 YEAR(Date) as Year,
 COUNT(*) as items0_Count
  FROM table
 WHERE   items_total in (1,0)
 GROUP BY Company, YEAR(Date)
 ORDER BY Company, YEAR(Date)
```